# Moment of Inertia calculation

Tags: javascript, timer, physics-engine

I am playing around with building a 2dPhysics engine in JavaScript and have been using this very helpful [blog post](http://buildnewgames.com/gamephysics/), which gives the following [example on codepen](http://jsfiddle.net/bkanber/9VdnU/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=9VdnU). In the example, the moment of inertia for the rect object is calculated as:

```
this.J = this.m * (this.height * this.height + this.width * this.width) / 12000;
```

which is based off the formula [image]

My question is why is this value scaled from 12 to 12000?

My assumption is that this is because the animation loop runs like this:

```
timer = setInterval(loop, dt * 1000);
```

where `dt` is the timestep as defined earlier in the logic:

```
dt = 0.02;
```

Is this multiplication just to account for JavaScript's millisecond based timer?

Comment: What units is `m`? If it's grams (and the rest is regular in SI units), the factor of `1000` is obvious.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `m` is in kilograms. This example isn't explicit about that, but the previous example in the same blog post explicates kilograms.